# Can someone please explain the ending of Shiki?

Tags: shiki

Did the whole village get burned down? How about the girl? The whole thing seems quite incomplete to me. Can someone explain the ending?

Answer (score 3):

Sunako and the monk got away. And probably began spreading their disease from there. They will most likely stick to low level feeding rather than the full village conversion. Since that turned out really bad.

The vampires were clearly aggressors as they preyed on the villagers. We start out really hating the vampires. In addition to that, we also hate the villagers too for being so docile and complacent. They had numerous warnings that they were being attacked by vampires, but no one took it seriously. Eventually the doctor and the monk figured it out but the doctor quickly turned into a blood feud.

By the end of the season, we no longer feel sorry for the villagers as they have now banded together and have turned the tide of the war. Instead, we feel sorry for the vampires since only a small handful of them actually attempted to fight back. The vampire faction were simply not prepared for a united front. Ninety percent of the vampires were simply running away with white flags over their heads. And the villagers pretty much demolished them.

The writers wants us to feel sorry for the vampires especially how sad music kept playing whenever one of them died. The story was pretty tragic.

There was definitely a better way to settle this. But that would make an uninteresting story. Like authorities could be called in. Police, soldiers, and helicopters could gun the vampires down and then strap their immortal bodies to a stretcher. And then send them to some underground military clinic to run experiments on them. lol. Help find a cure and also produce new vampires without the bloodsucking and daylight phobia drawbacks. lol

Anyways. Watching the villagers go vigilante was definitely an interesting turn. Just bodies everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's an open-ended finale. After the credits, there are still 30 seconds that you might have missed. All this is conjecture: the village burned but as fire pass away (purification) the survivors rebuilt it and the villagers' life goes on. The only Shiki whose status we're not sure about (for romantic reasons) are Sunako, the little girl of the mansion, and the head monk; either they burnt in the church or survived.

Comment: when you stop the episode in the ending you see a grey car going in the other direction with the monk in it!

Answer (score 2):

It was interesting to say the least but as many people have said it seems incomplete

The ending of shiki was an open ending where the viewer has to imagine for him/her self what happened

In the end it does show that the monk survived and had a briefcase (with the girl inside) driving down what we can only assume is the national road spoken of in the anime

This kind of ending also allows a continuation of it Mabey a shiki2 or season 2 Mabey from the vampires perspective who knows

But since it was ended in 2010 8 years ago its unlikely of animators to make another season (as sad as that may be)

One real question is how did the boy get back when he was tied up for the vampire (Mabey it was explained and I missed it but if not I'd like to know)

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site about anime & manga. This is not a forum, in which users discuss anything related to the topic. So, regarding your question at the end, consider posting it as a new question so that the community can answer it. Meanwhile, consider to also take a quick [tour] to understand more how this site works.

Comment: Your last question is very good, simply ask it as a new question. Answer are only for answers :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there were a few seconds after the ending credits and it was more of an open ending I personally take solace in how it ended being that I myself could not find a better way to end it that supported the themes and messages it seemed to convey. The point is that nothing is truly good and nothing is truly evil. Both the humans and vampires committed immoral acts towards one another with self preservation in mind  All that exists is perspective there were a few other anime I enjoyed that made me feel the same way over the years. Shiki being recently added to that list. But boy was that a sad anime the truth is blunt and unyielding.